# MongoDB: Get all collections in one document

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I´ve got in some trouble with Javascript and mongoDB. I connected via:

```
var db = mongo.db(config.connectionString, { native_parser: true });
```

and bind my visitors collection `db.bind('visitors');`. So after I tried to get all documents in there with that line:

```
db.visitors.find(function (err, visitors) {
   if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
   deferred.resolve(visitors);
});
```

So everything looks fine for me. But I get this error every time:

> angular.js:12011 GET http://localhost:3000/api/visitors/getAll 400
>   (Bad Request)

I thought its something with my api so I tried `...findOne({_id:1},..` and that worked. So did I missed something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is wrong. It should be:

```
db.visitors.find({}, function (err, visitors) {
   if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
   deferred.resolve(visitors);
});
```

The parameters are:

`collection.find(query[[[, fields], options], callback]);`

It expects a query first then a callback and you're providing the callback in first place.

Your test with `findOne()` works because you're passing in a query via the `{_ id: 1}` object.

The documentation about MongoDB queries in Node.js is [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html).

**Edit:**

An example of using `.find()` and handling the cursor object in an async way by converting it to an array:

```
db.visitors.find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(docs);
});
```

Comment: Are you taking into account that `.find({})` will return a cursor object instead of .findOne() which will return just an object? You will have to handle the visitors result: `var cursor = collection.find({});` and then `cursor.each(...);` or convert it to an array.

Comment: How can I do that ? I tried it with an .each function but its async to the rest so I cant return it in my function

Comment: I edited my answer to provide an example of handling the returned cursor object.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you missed the parameters part of the `find()`.  Even if you don't want to look for something specific you have to pass an empty object in the parameters part.  So it should look like `find({}, function(){...});`